# Thread safe way to fill/remove items in list

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 2 secondary threads running in an C# Win Application.

The first thread reads Sql Server profile messages and adds it as a string to a list box to form a sort of queue.
The other thread will send these trace messages one by one and correspondingly remove them from the list.

Now I am very much sure that it will cause problems. Any way to make sure that only a single thread will be able to access one of the two functions:

```
    void AddItemThreadSafe(string item)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            listBoxCollection.Items.Add(item);
        });
    }

    void RemoveItemThreadSafe()
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            listBoxCollection.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        });
    }
```

Comment: The good news is that the `Invoke` method on the form already synchronizes for you. That's the whole point of `Invoke`: to queue the method/delegate so that it runs on the one and only UI thread that created the form.

Comment: can u pls post that as an answer with some more details so that i can mark it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is that the `Invoke` method on the form already synchronizes for you. That's the whole point of `Invoke`: to queue the method/delegate so that it runs on the one and only UI thread that created the form.

Comment: I dont know the details nor do I know exactly if it's correct but it does sound correct.

Answer (score 5):

In general, use a `lock` to synchronize thread access to a section of code.

```
private static object listLocker = new object();

void AddItemThreadSafe(string item)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        lock (listLocker)
        {
            listBoxCollection.Items.Add(item);
        }
    });
}

void RemoveItemThreadSafe()
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        lock (listLocker)
        {
            listBoxCollection.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    });
}
```

In this particular case (someone correct me if I'm wrong), I believe the fact that you are invoking the methods from the same object already synchronizes the access, making the lock redundant.

Comment: Yep, the Invoke looks like it will make locking redundant as all access will occur on the same (UI) Thread (and therefore can never be concurrent).

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [Thread-Safe Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx)
like [ConcurrentBag Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx)

From your question Isaw that you need some kind of queue, so use [ConcurrentQueue Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx)